# Javascript iterators don't workk

Tags: javascript, iterator

```
class List{
  constructor(){
    this.data = [1,2,3];
  }

  [Symbol.iterator](){
    return this.data;
  }

}


let list = new List();
for(let i of list)
  console.log(i);
```

Error in the for() line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So it's not possible to use iterator with our own classes like in PHP?

Comment: I think you need to return an iterator, not an iterable – `return this.data[Symbol.iterator]()`

Comment: I fixed it with `*[Symbol.iterator](){
    for(let i of this.data)
      yield i;
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't working because you have not properly implemented the iterable protocol. For an object to be an iterable, it must have an `@@iterator` key (which you have), *which returns an iterator*, which is what you are missing (arrays are iterables but are not iterators).

However, since an array is an iterable, you can use its `@@iterator` property to get an iterable for it. Then you can return that instead.

```js
class List{
  constructor(){
    this.data = [1,2,3];
  }

  [Symbol.iterator](){
    return this.data[Symbol.iterator]();
  }

}


let list = new List();
for(let i of list)
  console.log(i);
```

You can read more about the [Javascript iterable/iterator protocol here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

Answer (score 2):

You can make the the `[Symbol.iterator]` property of you object a generator rather than a function and just yield the list elements individually with `*`:

```js
class List {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [1, 2, 3];
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield* this.data;
  }

}

let list = new List();
for (let i of list) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Ah! Ninja'd! I shall delete my answer.